# react native : there is way to message to the screen if axios id fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

there is way to make a message to the screen when the get axios is fail .
how to do it ?

this is my example code :

```
getData = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, data: [] });
    var userPrincipalName = this.state.userPrincipalName;
    ///for debbugin only--NEED TO CHANGE "THE_NAME_USER" TO "userPrincipalName" IN THE AXIOS
    THE_NAME_USER = "apaz";
    axios
      .get(
        "https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/OrderApprove/OrderApp_Get_Orders_To_Approve/" +
          THE_NAME_USER
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data: res.data
        });
        InfoStore.setList(res.data);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to display an error message when something happens when API failed.

Check below example & change this according to your requirements.

```
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        isError: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        return axios
            .get("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: response.data.movies
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    isError: true
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
                {
                    // Shows loding indicator until data loads
                    this.state.isLoading ?
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                            <ActivityIndicator />
                        </View>
                        :
                        // Shows an error if an error occured
                        this.state.isError ?
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <Text>Oops  error while loading</Text>
                            </View>
                            :
                            // Display data after successful fetch 
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.data}
                                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                    <Text>
                                        {item.title}, {item.releaseYear}
                                    </Text>
                                )}
                                keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
                            />
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, use two ".then" statement like this

```
axios.get("https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/OrderApprove/OrderApp_Get_Orders_To_Approve/" +
          THE_NAME_USER
      ).then(response =>
  {
    const statusCode = response.status;
    const data = response.json();
    return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
  }).then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: res.data
                });
                InfoStore.setList(res.data);
                // console.log("InfoStore get;List", InfoStore.getList.slice());
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                alert(“your error is here”)
        });
```

First ".then" actually deal HTTP response of your API call, if it's not working or error happens then it gives respective error code (for example, in success case it makes "200 OK" and error case return 500 or other error codes). you can easily show alert on these status code and check your api call data accordingly. error codes description are available on this link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: can you explain more,  actually what do you need?

Comment: i need to write to screen this message : " hi this is error "

Comment: i edit my code, can you show me in my new change how to do the message " hi this is error " to scrren ?